# qsub is working but qrsh fails and only when resources are specified explicitly with -l. Why?

Tags: gridengine, grid

I am getting the following error while submitting a simple interactive job to open a shell: `qrsh -V -cwd -verbose -q nsnel6.q -l h_vmem=12.000G tcsh`

```
local configuration arslox51 not defined - using global configuration
Your job 8450878 ("tcsh") has been submitted
waiting for interactive job to be scheduled ...timeout (5 s) expired while waiting on socket fd 4


Your "qrsh" request could not be scheduled, try again later.
```

The job succeeds when submitted without resources specified.

Also I have checked the resources and they are available. And they are more than 30 hosts and many jobs are running. But the resources are more than enough.

qsub works with the same resources but only qrsh is facing this issue. Only a very few times it's working in qrsh.

Is it anything  to do with this error `local configuration arslox51 not defined - using global configuration`? And also what is this error about?

My SGE version is 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qrsh fails because qsub is using all the resources.

The qrsh command could wait by using -now n option.